# Genymotion emulator not detecting sound

Tags: android, genymotion

I am creating a camera application that detects claps, however the sound detection does not work in genymotion but only works in the regular emulator. I am not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in the windows version of Genymotion that prevent the input sound from working. 
It works well on Linux and Mac but not on Windows. 
There is no way to work around it at this time.